# Remove user from Azure subscription

Tags: azure

I just removed myself from the list of owners from an Azure subscription. Yet, I am still able to access the subscription and see all it's resources. I also seem to have the ability to cancel subscriptions, add roles etc.

Does it take some time for the removal to take effect? The wait time so far has been 4 hours. I have made sure that I am not part of any other groups that have contributor/admin/owner access.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you a subscription admin? That's above Owner, not part of the normal RBAC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing yourself from the list of owners from an Azure subscription, you need to sign out and sign in again.

I have tried this on my side. I have only one role(owner) and I removed myself. Then sign out and sign in again. I will have no access to this subscription and resources.

[image]

If this doesn't work for you. Just like @juunas said, check if you are the admin of this subscription.
[image]